# 私は日本語と英語で思っています。

Tags: grammar, translation

Is this the proper way to say "I think in Japanese and English", or should I be using a particle other than で?

Answer (score 8):

The issue is in the verb choice, not in the particle.  The **only** possible particle is indeed で.  If that is not used, the longer phrase 「～～を使って」 will have to be used.

The verb to use here is 考える, not 思う.  思う is too passive in meaning.

Native speakers would say:

> 「（私は）日本語と英語で考えています。」 or
>
> 「（私は）日本語と英語の両方で考えています。」

Comment: +1 for suggesting 考える instead of 思う